# Load both index.html and index.php in a frame using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, frame

I have 2 pages (**index.html** and **index.php**) that both need to load within a frame in my main page. The **index.html** only contains an audio player and therefore continues to play when I view the menu of the **index.php**. That's why I put those 2 pages in a frame.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThSpe.jpg)

I have tried to use **DirectoryIndex index.html index.php** but then the **index.html** does load a number of times while the **index.php** does not load at all.
After working on this for 2 days I thought I would look for some help here.
So does anyone know a solution for this issue?

Comment: What does DirectoryIndex have to do with this? If you want to load a specific document into one of your frames, then why are you not using the explicit URL to that file?

Comment: I want the **index.html** and **index.php** to load in https://example.com. If I use the explicit URL https://example.com/index.html the visitors would indeed get to see both files but if they somehow skip back to https://example.com they will only see the **index.php**.

Comment: You should make your index document your frameset, and then load two documents into those frames explicitly via their file name. There is no real need to rely on DirectoryIndex for the latter two.

Comment: I think I did that already. This is the ![index.html](https://64.media.tumblr.com/5af1b51738e316d2f3bc311c1aa4b457/47f23436b7e265ae-2a/s1280x1920/16ab40158c7001d81ee59dccdefcd4459feb6c06.pnj).

Comment: Not sure what the problem is supposed to be. What does _"but then the index.html does load a number of times"_ mean?